# What makes these two R data frames not identical?

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

I have two small data frames, `this_tx` and `last_tx`.  They are, in every way that I can tell, completely identical.  `this_tx` == `last_tx` results in a frame of identical dimensions, all `TRUE`.  `this_tx %in% last_tx`, two `TRUEs`.  Inspected visually, clearly identical.  But when I call

`identical(this_tx, last_tx)`

I get a `FALSE`.  Hilariously, even

`identical(str(this_tx), str(last_tx))`

will return a `TRUE`.  If I set `this_tx <- last_tx`, I'll get a `TRUE`.

What is going on?  I don't have the deepest understanding of R's internal mechanics, but I can't find a single difference between the two data frames.  If it's relevant, the two variables in the frames are both factors - same levels, same numeric coding for the levels, both just subsets of the same original data frame.  Converting them to character vectors doesn't help.

Background (because I wouldn't mind help on this, either): I have records of drug treatments given to patients.  Each treatment record essentially specifies a person and a date.  A second table has a record for each drug and dose given during a particular treatment (usually, a few drugs are given each treatment).  I'm trying to identify contiguous periods during which the person was taking the same combinations of drugs at the same doses.

The best plan I've come up with is to check the treatments chronologically.  If the combination of drugs and doses for treatment[i] is identical to the combination at treatment[i-1], then treatment[i] is a part of the same phase as treatment[i-1].  Of course, if I can't compare drug/dose combinations, that's right out.

Comment: If you could post an example pair of data frames it would help- preferably as the result of running `dput()` on the frames.

Comment: Sharpie wins. The two data frames were still carrying the row.names of the mother data frame, which shows up in a dput() but not str(). Sharpie, if you post as an answer, I'll mark it best.

Comment: I'm actually surprised- I always thought `str` was a "prettified" version of `dput`.  Guess it turns out that it is just a summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the jaded cry of "moar specifics plz!" may win in this case:

Check the output of `dput()` and post if possible. `str()` just summarizes the contents of an object whilst `dput()` dumps out all the gory details in a form that may be copied and pasted into another R interpreter to regenerate the object.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, in this situation it's useful to try `all.equal` which will give you some information about why two objects are not equivalent.

Comment: I did try this and got a rather cryptic `"Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 0.01158301 >"`, which is what led me to str() the data frames - but "Attributes: Component 2" didn't really lead me to the row numbers.